# Moving subforms in standard PDF

Tags: pdf, dynamic, click, livecycle, subforms

I am trying to move subforms in a standard pdf file (not a dynamic XML). I have an old copy of LiveCycle (ES2) and have produced the following code

```
xfa.host.setFocus(clearArrows);

var gridX = xfa.layout.x(gridPICK); 
var gridY = xfa.layout.y(gridPICK); 
var gridW = xfa.layout.w(gridPICK);
var gridH = xfa.layout.h(gridPICK);

var markerDim = 0;

var mouseX = event.target.mouseX;
var newX = (mouseX + "points").toString(); 
var mouseY = xfa.layout.h(Page3) - event.target.mouseY;
var newY = (mouseY + "points").toString(); 

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    var indicatorObject = xfa.resolveNode("Indicator[" + i.toString() +     "]");
    var indicatorX = xfa.layout.x(indicatorObject);
    if (indicatorX < gridX) {
        var pointIndicator = indicatorObject;
        pointIndicator.presence = "visible"; 
        xfa.host.setFocus(pointIndicator.Description);
        xfa.host.openList("Indicator[" + i.toString() + "].Description");

        i = 10;
    }

}



if (mouseX <= gridX + markerDim)
{
    pointIndicator.x = (gridX + markerDim + "points").toString(); 
}
else if (mouseX >= gridX + gridW - markerDim)
{
    pointIndicator.x = (gridX + gridW - markerDim + "points").toString();  
}
else
{
    pointIndicator.x = newX; 
} 

if (mouseY >= gridY + gridH - markerDim)
{
    pointIndicator.y = (gridY + gridH - markerDim + "points").toString();  
}
else if (mouseY <= gridY + markerDim)
{
    pointIndicator.y = (gridY + markerDim + "points").toString(); 
}
else
{
    pointIndicator.y = newY;
}
```

This works fine if I extend the features and use it on a PC or mac however if I try to use it on an ipad it does not work. Essentially this code is placed on the click event of a large button in a grid square.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm surprised by your statement that the form works on a PC when saved as a static XFA PDF form.  I wouldn't expect that to work except as a dynamic XFA PDF form.  What event are you using to trigger this code?  The click event?

I would expect this to work when rendering the form however once the form is rendered as a static XFA PDF, it's not generally possible to move subforms around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid I don't think you'll be able to get this to work.

The iPad version of Adobe Reader [does not support XFA forms](https://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/acrobatetk/tools/Mobile/iosapi/index.html) designed in LiveCycle Designer.